# Custom Filter for Laravel Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to make some custom filters for my Laravel application.

In filter.php I have

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest() AND ! Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        return 'Not Authorized';
    }
});
```

User.php model

```
public function isAdmin()
{
  if($this->role==1) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

And finally in the Route:

```
//SECTIONS ONLY FOR ADMIN
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admins', 'before' => array('admin')), function(){

    Route::get('/frontoffice', 'FrontofficeController@index');
    Route::get('/frontoffice/about', 'FrontofficeController@about');
    Route::get('/frontoffice/research', 'FrontofficeController@research');
});
```

I'm logged in as an Admin in my application, but still I'm getting `NotFoundHttpException` when I try to access the above URLs in the route.

Any idea why?

Comment: Try using OR in your filter:
    if (Auth::guest() || ! Auth::user()->isAdmin())

Comment: Just a note - your admin filter won't work as expected. `||` should be used instead of `AND`, otherwise it will fail against regular authenticated users. `isAdmin` method could also be improved to make it more readable - `return $this->role == 1` should suffice.